# Replacing the last column in a unix file with another value

Tags: unix, vim, replace, sed

I would like to replace the last column values with another value using vim editor or sed command.I tried the below command but it replaces the data which is already present in my 2nd column sometimes.

```
:%s/,3/,2/
```

My sample data:

```
410339,166,1430,3
410340,112,1840,3
410341,109,1315,3
410342,123,1435,3
410343,230,3200,3
410344,857,36975,3
410345,125,4440,3
410346,105,1460,3
410348,122,1150,3
410349,314,2380,3
410350,132,4650,3
410351,136,7465,3
410352,103,1775,3
410353,101,1095,3
410354,101,1360,3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To complete your attempt in Vim, just anchor the matched expression to the end of the line with `$`.

```
:%s/,3$/,2/
```

Produces:

```
410339,166,1430,2
410340,112,1840,2
410341,109,1315,2
410342,123,1435,2
410343,230,3200,2
410344,857,36975,2
410345,125,4440,2
410346,105,1460,2
410348,122,1150,2
410349,314,2380,2
410350,132,4650,2
410351,136,7465,2
410352,103,1775,2
410353,101,1095,2
410354,101,1360,2
```

Comment: What is the point of the global flag, when the pattern is being anchored to the end of the line?

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to indicate that you want the end-of-line:

```
:%s/,3$/2/
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use `awk`:

```
awk '{$NF=2}1' FS=, OFS=,
```

This unconditionally makes the last column have the value 2.  If the desired replacement is a string, you will need to use quotes or the more flexible:

```
awk '{$NF=r}1' FS=, OFS=, r="the string to put in the last column"
```

You can restrict the replacement to those columns that have the value 3 with:

```
awk '$NF==3{$NF=r}1' FS=, OFS=, r="the string to put in the last column"
```

And, to do this in vim, just do:

```
:%! awk ...
```

Answer (score 2):

With `GNU sed`:

If the last column is only ever '3':

```
sed -i 's/3$/2/' file
```

If the last column could be something like '13':

```
sed -i 's/,3$/,2/' file
```

The `-i` flag:

```
-i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
    edit files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)
```